# При получении push уведомления, отправлять данные на сервер

Tags: android, push-уведомления, fcm

Я использую FCM для получения уведомлений. При получении уведомления, устройство должно отправить данные на сервер. Если устройство не заблокировано, то есть включен экран и т д. Данные отправляются, если его заблокировать, то приходит просто звуковое оповещение и всё. При вызове onMessageReceived вызываю Log.d. Но если устройство заблокировано, то log даже не отображается. И естественно никакие данные на сервер не отправляются. Устройство xiaomi. На самсунге всё ок. Погуглил, и увидел что я не один такой. Есть ли сегодня способ борьбы с китайскими устройствами, и их агрессивными оболочками?

Comment: А как вы пуш отправляете? Data или Notification пуш у вас?

Comment: Notification. Но ща пишется сервер на шарпе. В нём fb admin  будем использовать. Мне вообще, по хорошему тихие пуши нужны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отправляйте уведомление с блоком Data, а не Notification, тогда вы обработаете в методе данные, после этого запустите workmanager с задачей разовой, чтобы выполнить её и в ней передайте данные на сервер. С китайскими девайсами нужно быть осторожнее, у них свои костыли, которые могут грохать работу в бэкграунде. Поэтому поищите на тему отключения оптимизации бэкграунд работы на xiaomi устройствах, там есть такое

Comment: В офф документации, пишется использовать fb job dispatcher для работы более 10 сек. Я считал что на 10 секунд устройство принудительно выйдет из Doze. А у меня задачи не такие нагруженные, разве что трэд. Я к тому, нужны ли мне вообще эти планировщик?

Comment: @Domex, вы, наверное, какую-то старую доку читаете. fb job dispatcher 
 устарел, надо workmanager 
 использовать: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/migrating-fb

Comment: Сейчас я отправляю уведомления через окно проекта Firebase. Там и ввожу custom data. Но когда уведомление приходит, то data null и notification null. Можно ли вообще через консоль Firebase отправлять уведомления с data?

Comment: Для backgraund задач, которые должны быть точно выполнены юзайте workmanager, всё остальное - шило

Comment: Юзаю work manager, координаты gps приходят одни и те же. Примерно через 20 минут работы при звблокированнлм устройстве. Делаю через fusedlocationprovoderxlient. Тогда решил написать отдельный сервис а в ворке, через бинд получать координаты. Но не прокатило. Всё равно одинаковые. Мб есть идеи?

Comment: Не знаю, актуальна ли геолокация для этого раздела? Или нужно задать другой вопрос?

Comment: Нужно задать другой вопрос